# Landscape mode for app?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, layout

### TL;DR: When  turning my phone to landscape, `layout-land` layout doesn't show up

I have made 8 new layouts for each layout in order to work for every screen size. This took me about 5 hours, but I finally got it done. When I tested it on my phone, and changed to landscape mode, the landscape layout didn't show!

[image]

Why is this? Is it a problem with my directory names? Here is the project view:

[image]

Why isn't the appropriate layout showing? Have I done something wrong and wasted my last 4+ hours by making layouts for each? If you need any more information, feel free to ask for it.

Here is my manifest:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b875163fe52eb03629b

Here's another similar question I asked, which didn't get any proper answers *yet*:

[Are there problems with my folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428750/are-there-problems-with-my-folders?noredirect=1#comment56601052_34428750)

Comment: A similar issue was posted before, I hope [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode) helps.

Comment: @Saiprasant Yes, and I have the appropriate directories, but try, it doesn't work. Let me know

Comment: had you given orientation:"portrait" to activity in manifest?

Comment: @AjinkyaPatil I have not...I have updated my question with the manifest. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b875163fe52eb03629b

Comment: these qualifiers are deprecated for creating different folders for layout. Use sw<N>dp qualifiers for your different layout folders.Check the link from android developers site [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
May be that's causing issue

Comment: @VivekMishra Although it is deprecated, it should still work, right?

Comment: so which phone do you have?