# Are there problems with my folders?

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, android-layout

Earlier, I asked this question:
[Landscape mode for app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app)

Where I had a directory for each and every layout, but the layout in the `layout-land` directory wasn't showing up when positioning my layout in landscape orientation. [image]

So, someone suggested to me that it maybe that the

### `Layout-normal` directories are overriding my regular `layout-land` directories. Is this true?

If so, will any other of my layout folders get overriding? What is the purpose of `layout-normal` in the first place then anyway?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: I think `layout-land` would be called instead of the other `layout-land-*` directories

Comment: yes this happened with me too. I had small,normal and large directories but for normal screens also layout from small folder was choosen by android.

Comment: and Kyle is right naming should be like that

Comment: @VivekMishra Really? What did you do to fix it? Did you remove the normal directory?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel There are no `layout-land-*` directories...?

Comment: no deleted small directory as it was for screen size around 2 to 3 inches and that phone sizes are very rare now and also I already know that my app won't be running on such small screen size

Comment: did you created folder manually or using graphical view from android studio??

Comment: Not manually. I clicked on settings icon in graphic view - > create other. Then made the directories. @VivekMishra

Comment: that's not correct.right click on res folder then new and then new resource directory. From there selected orientation and then landscape

Comment: @RuchirBaronia it's a typo, my bad. I meant that the `layout-land` folder would be called rather than the specific `layout-*-land` folders.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel Really? So should I delete that?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel How do you know?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia you can try to see for yourself. I don't use specific screen sizes for my graphics.

Answer (score 0):

First understand, how resources are pulled out in android. If your device is `large`, then the `layout` from `layout-large` gets loaded. If you device is `normal` then the `layout` from `layout-normal` gets loaded. But if the android system is unable to determine whether the device is `large` or `normal` or anything else. Then layouts from the `layout` get loaded.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. If you look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378238/landscape-mode-for-app?lq=1) You'll see that I do have all of the appropriate directories. The issue I'm having is that even when I put my `normal` size screen to `landscape` mode, the regular `layout` mode gets loaded.

Comment: Make a back up of the `layout-land` and then delete the folder. Now try to run and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, I will do that, but I only have so many devices to test on and catch these issues. So does anything else override anything?

Comment: From the way i see it, you have all the screen sizes handled. That is `small`, `normal`, `large`, `xlarge`. So i don't think there would be any other problems. Lastly, as you already know it is recommended to use `sw` qualifiers.